# DMA Transfer Complete call is not synchronized with the SPI on STM32F446

Tags: stm32, spi, dma, stm32f4

I want to use an STM32F446RE-Nucleo board to readout an MCP3201 ADC at a regular frequency. I want to perform the communication with the ADC using SPI and DMA to write the data directly into the memory.

My code (displayed below) for the STM32F446RE is structured as follows:

- The SysTick interrupt (set at 18 kHz) is used to start SPI communication. SPI2 and DMA1 are enabled, output signal CS is pulled low, as required by the ADC
- A DMA Receive Complete callback is used to terminate the SPI communication after a 16-bit sample has been read. SPI2 and DMA1 are disabled and CS is pulled high.

The SPI properly generates a 16-cycle clock signal, but the CS signal is pulled high way too early, as I can see on the oscilloscope (clock signal on top, CS signal on the bottom):

[image]

What am I doing wrong, that causes the DMA1_Stream3_IRQHandler being called after 2 bits instead of after receiving all 16 bits of data?

```
    #include "main.h"

    #define SYS_CLK_FREQ 100000000 //100 MHz
    #define SYSTICK_FREQ 18000 //18 kHz
    #define ADC_SCK_PIN  LL_GPIO_PIN_13 //PB13
    #define ADC_MISO_PIN LL_GPIO_PIN_14 //PB14
    #define ADC_CS_PIN   LL_GPIO_PIN_15 //PB15
    #define BUFFER_SIZE 16 //RX Buffer size

    __IO   uint32_t uwMeasuredFrequency = 0; //measured freq
    static uint32_t TimOutClock = 1; // TIM2 Clock
    static uint8_t bit = 0;
    static uint8_t initFinished = 0;
    uint16_t aRxBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    // Private function prototypes 
    __STATIC_INLINE void     SystemClock_Config(void);
    __STATIC_INLINE void     Configure_Frequency(uint32_t Frequency);
    __STATIC_INLINE void     LED_Init(void);
    __STATIC_INLINE void     LED_Blinking(uint32_t Period);
    __STATIC_INLINE void     UserButton_Init(void);
    __STATIC_INLINE void     Configure_SPI2 (void);
    __STATIC_INLINE void     Configure_DMA1 (void);

    void DMA1_ReceiveComplete_Callback (void);


    /** @brief  Main program */
    int main(void) {
      SystemClock_Config(); // Configure the system clock to 100 MHz
      LED_Init();           // Initialize LED2
      UserButton_Init();    // Initialize button in EXTI mode 
      Configure_SPI2 ();
      Configure_DMA1 ();
      initFinished = 1;
      while (1) {}
    }

    /**
    * @brief  Periodic call, using the SysTick handler. This starts communication with the ADC, that will
    * send a data sample.
    * @param  None
    * @retval None
    */
    void SysTick_Handler (void)
    {
      //LL_GPIO_SetOutputPin (LED2_GPIO_PORT, LED2_PIN); 
      /* Activate SPI 2 */
      if (initFinished) {
         LL_GPIO_ResetOutputPin (GPIOB, ADC_CS_PIN); //Pull CS low, to start ADC sampling
         LL_SPI_Enable (SPI2);
         LL_DMA_EnableStream (DMA1, LL_DMA_STREAM_3);
      }
    }

    /**
    * @brief  Function called when a sample has been received from the ADC. It can be stored or processed.
    * @param  None
    * @retval None
    */
    void DMA1_ReceiveComplete_Callback (void) {
      LL_DMA_DisableStream (DMA1, LL_DMA_STREAM_3);
      LL_SPI_Disable (SPI2);
      uint16_t sample = aRxBuffer[0];
      //LL_GPIO_SetOutputPin (GPIOB, ADC_CS_PIN);
      LL_GPIO_TogglePin (GPIOB, ADC_CS_PIN);

    }

    /**
    * @brief  This function configures SPI2.
    * @note  This function is used to :
    *        -1- Enables GPIO clock and configures the SPI2 pins.
    *        -2- Configure SPI2 functional parameters.
    * @note   Peripheral configuration is minimal configuration from reset values.
    *         Thus, some useless LL unitary functions calls below are provided as
    *         commented examples - setting is default configuration from reset.
    * @param  None
    * @retval None
    */
    __STATIC_INLINE void Configure_SPI2 (void) {
      /* (1) Enables GPIO clock and configures the SPI2 pins ********************/

      /* Enable the peripheral clock of GPIOB */
      LL_AHB1_GRP1_EnableClock (LL_AHB1_GRP1_PERIPH_ALL); //(LL_AHB1_GRP1_PERIPH_GPIOB) ;


      /* Configure SCK Pin connected to pin PB13 of CN10 connector */
      LL_GPIO_SetPinMode    (GPIOB, ADC_SCK_PIN, LL_GPIO_MODE_ALTERNATE);
      LL_GPIO_SetAFPin_8_15 (GPIOB, ADC_SCK_PIN, LL_GPIO_AF_5);
      LL_GPIO_SetPinSpeed   (GPIOB, ADC_SCK_PIN, LL_GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH);
      LL_GPIO_SetPinPull    (GPIOB, ADC_SCK_PIN, LL_GPIO_PULL_DOWN);

      /* Configure MISO Pin connected to pin PB14 of CN10 connector */
      LL_GPIO_SetPinMode    (GPIOB, ADC_MISO_PIN, LL_GPIO_MODE_ALTERNATE);
      LL_GPIO_SetAFPin_8_15 (GPIOB, ADC_MISO_PIN, LL_GPIO_AF_5);
      LL_GPIO_SetPinSpeed   (GPIOB, ADC_MISO_PIN, LL_GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH);
      LL_GPIO_SetPinPull    (GPIOB, ADC_MISO_PIN, LL_GPIO_PULL_DOWN);


      /* Configure CS Pin connected to pin PB15*/
      LL_GPIO_SetPinMode (GPIOB, ADC_CS_PIN, LL_GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
      LL_GPIO_SetPinSpeed (GPIOB, ADC_CS_PIN, LL_GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH);
      LL_GPIO_SetPinPull (GPIOB, ADC_CS_PIN, LL_GPIO_PULL_NO);

      /* (2) Configure SPI2 functional parameters ********************************/
      /* Enable the peripheral clock of GPIOB */
      LL_APB1_GRP1_EnableClock (LL_APB1_GRP1_PERIPH_SPI2);

      /* Configure SPI2 communication */
      LL_SPI_SetBaudRatePrescaler (SPI2, LL_SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_DIV64);
      LL_SPI_SetTransferDirection (SPI2, LL_SPI_SIMPLEX_RX);
      LL_SPI_SetClockPhase (SPI2, LL_SPI_PHASE_2EDGE);
      LL_SPI_SetClockPolarity (SPI2, LL_SPI_POLARITY_LOW);
      LL_SPI_SetTransferBitOrder (SPI2, LL_SPI_MSB_FIRST); //already the default value
      LL_SPI_SetDataWidth (SPI2, LL_SPI_DATAWIDTH_16BIT);
      LL_SPI_SetNSSMode (SPI2, LL_SPI_NSS_SOFT);
      LL_SPI_SetMode (SPI2, LL_SPI_MODE_MASTER);  //I am the master! Give me samples!

      /* Enable DMA RX Interrupt */
      LL_SPI_EnableDMAReq_RX (SPI2);
    }

    /**
    * @brief  This function configures the DMA1 Channels for SPI2
    * @note  This function is used to :
    *        -1- Enable DMA1 clock
    *        -2- Configure NVIC for DMA1 transfer complete/error interrupts
    *        -3- Configure the DMA1_Stream3 functional parameters
    *        -4- Enable DMA1 interrupts complete/error
    * @param   None
    * @retval  None
    */
    __STATIC_INLINE void Configure_DMA1 (void) {
      // DMA1 used for SPI2 Reception
      LL_AHB1_GRP1_EnableClock (LL_AHB1_GRP1_PERIPH_DMA1); // Enable DMA1-clock

      /* (2) Configure NVIC for DMA transfer complete/error interrupts */
      NVIC_SetPriority (DMA1_Stream3_IRQn, 0);
      NVIC_EnableIRQ (DMA1_Stream3_IRQn);

      /* (4) Configure the DMA1_Stream3 functional parameters */
      LL_DMA_ConfigTransfer (DMA1,
         LL_DMA_STREAM_3,
         LL_DMA_DIRECTION_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY | LL_DMA_PRIORITY_HIGH | LL_DMA_MODE_NORMAL |
         LL_DMA_PERIPH_NOINCREMENT | LL_DMA_MEMORY_INCREMENT |
         LL_DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE | LL_DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE);
      LL_DMA_ConfigAddresses (DMA1, 
         LL_DMA_STREAM_3,
         LL_SPI_DMA_GetRegAddr (SPI2),
         (uint32_t)aRxBuffer,
         LL_DMA_GetDataTransferDirection (DMA1, LL_DMA_STREAM_3));
      LL_DMA_SetDataLength (DMA1, LL_DMA_STREAM_3, 1); //We receive 1 sample (16-bit)

      LL_DMA_SetChannelSelection (DMA1, LL_DMA_STREAM_3, LL_DMA_CHANNEL_0);

      /* (5) Enable DMA interrupts complete/error */
      LL_DMA_EnableIT_TC (DMA1, LL_DMA_STREAM_3);
      LL_DMA_EnableIT_TE (DMA1, LL_DMA_STREAM_3);
    }



    /**
    * @brief  Initialize LED2.
    * @param  None
    * @retval None
    */
    __STATIC_INLINE void LED_Init(void) {
      LED2_GPIO_CLK_ENABLE();
      LL_GPIO_SetPinMode(LED2_GPIO_PORT, LED2_PIN, LL_GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    }


    /**
    * @brief  Configures User push-button in GPIO or EXTI Line Mode.
    */
    __STATIC_INLINE void UserButton_Init(void) {
    USER_BUTTON_GPIO_CLK_ENABLE();

    LL_GPIO_SetPinMode(USER_BUTTON_GPIO_PORT, USER_BUTTON_PIN, LL_GPIO_MODE_INPUT);
    LL_GPIO_SetPinPull(USER_BUTTON_GPIO_PORT, USER_BUTTON_PIN, LL_GPIO_PULL_NO);

    USER_BUTTON_SYSCFG_SET_EXTI();

    USER_BUTTON_EXTI_LINE_ENABLE();
    USER_BUTTON_EXTI_FALLING_TRIG_ENABLE();

    NVIC_EnableIRQ(USER_BUTTON_EXTI_IRQn); 
    NVIC_SetPriority(USER_BUTTON_EXTI_IRQn,0x03);  
    }

    /**
    * @brief  System Clock Configuration
    *         The system Clock is configured as follow :
    *            System Clock source            = PLL (HSE)
    *            SYSCLK(Hz)                     = 100000000
    *            HCLK(Hz)                       = 100000000
    *            AHB Prescaler                  = 1
    *            APB1 Prescaler                 = 2
    *            APB2 Prescaler                 = 1
    *            HSE Frequency(Hz)              = 8000000
    *            PLL_M                          = 8
    *            PLL_N                          = 400
    *            PLL_P                          = 4
    *            VDD(V)                         = 3.3
    *            Main regulator output voltage  = Scale1 mode
    *            Flash Latency(WS)              = 3
    * @param  None
    * @retval None
    */
    void SystemClock_Config(void) {
      /* Enable HSE oscillator */
      LL_RCC_HSE_EnableBypass();
      LL_RCC_HSE_Enable();
      while(LL_RCC_HSE_IsReady() != 1) {};

      LL_FLASH_SetLatency(LL_FLASH_LATENCY_3);

      LL_RCC_PLL_ConfigDomain_SYS(LL_RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE, LL_RCC_PLLM_DIV_8, 400, LL_RCC_PLLP_DIV_4);
      LL_RCC_PLL_Enable();
      while(LL_RCC_PLL_IsReady() != 1) {}

      /* Sysclk activation on the main PLL */
      LL_RCC_SetAHBPrescaler(LL_RCC_SYSCLK_DIV_1);
      LL_RCC_SetSysClkSource(LL_RCC_SYS_CLKSOURCE_PLL);
      while (LL_RCC_GetSysClkSource () != LL_RCC_SYS_CLKSOURCE_STATUS_PLL) {}

      /* Set APB1 & APB2 prescaler */
      LL_RCC_SetAPB1Prescaler(LL_RCC_APB1_DIV_2);
      LL_RCC_SetAPB2Prescaler(LL_RCC_APB2_DIV_1);

      SysTick_Config (SYS_CLK_FREQ / SYSTICK_FREQ); // Set sysTick

      /* Update CMSIS variable (which can be updated also through SystemCoreClockUpdate function) */
      SystemCoreClock = SYS_CLK_FREQ;
    }

    /******************************************************************************/
    /*   USER IRQ HANDLER TREATMENT                                               */
    /******************************************************************************/
    /**
    * @brief  User button interrupt processing
    * @note   When the user key button is pressed the frequency of the  
    *         PWM signal generated by TIM2 is updated. 
    * @param  None
    * @retval None
    */
    void UserButton_Callback(void)
    {
    /* please do nothing yet*/
    }


    /**
    * @brief  This function handles external line 13 interrupt request.
    * @param  None
    * @retval None
    */
    void USER_BUTTON_IRQHANDLER (void)
    {
      /* Manage Flags */
      if (LL_EXTI_IsActiveFlag_0_31 (USER_BUTTON_EXTI_LINE) != RESET) {
         LL_EXTI_ClearFlag_0_31 (USER_BUTTON_EXTI_LINE);

         /* User button interrupt processing(function defined in main.c) */
         UserButton_Callback (); 
      }
    }

    void DMA1_Stream3_IRQHandler (void)
    {
      if (LL_DMA_IsActiveFlag_TC3 (DMA1))
      {
         LL_DMA_ClearFlag_TC3 (DMA1);
         /* Call function Reception complete Callback */
         DMA1_ReceiveComplete_Callback ();
      }
      else if (LL_DMA_IsActiveFlag_TE3 (DMA1))
      {
         /* TODO Call Error function */
      }

    }
```

Comment: What would you then prefer over using the HAL (that I don't use) or LL libraries? Using the LL library gives portability to other STM32 microprocessors. In the function `Configure_SPI2()` I configure the SPI module and set the data width to 16 bits, using `LL_SPI_SetDataWidth (SPI2, LL_SPI_DATAWIDTH_16BIT);`. In `Configure_DMA1()` I configure the DMA width to be received to 1 word (that should be 16-bit) using `LL_DMA_SetDataLength (DMA1, LL_DMA_STREAM_3, 1);`

Comment: I use only the the bare registers (and of course my own functions).